# Can I move Angular form validation to a different DOM element in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a currency input directive. It does some basic number validation and `$parse`-ing to return a number. Additionally, I want to put a `$` before the input using CSS `:before`. Problem is, you can't use `:before` on `<input>` elements.

My solution is to create the following directive (I've stripped out the validation besides `required` for simplicity):

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myCurrencyInput', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: ['ngModel', '^form'],
      scope: {
        ngModel: '='
      },
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/myCurrencyInput/myCurrencyInput.html',
      compile: function(element, attrs) {

        // The internal input to the directive
        var $input = element.children('input');

        if(attrs.required) {
          element.removeAttr('required');
          attrs.required = undefined;
          $input.attr('required', 'required');
        }

        if(attrs.name) {
          element.removeAttr('name');
          $input.attr('name', attrs.name);
          attrs.name = undefined;
        }

        return function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
          var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[0];
          var formCtrl = ctrls[1];
          var internalCtrl = element.find('input').controller('ngModel');

          if($input.attr('required') === 'required') {
            // formCtrl doesn't have ngModelCtrl attached at this point
            formCtrl.$removeControl(ngModelCtrl);
          }

          // Bind internal model changes to the outside ngModel
          scope.$watch('internalModel', function(newVal) {
            if(newVal !== undefined && newVal !== scope.ngModel) {
              scope.ngModel = newVal;
            }
          });

          // Bind external model changes to the inside ngModel (internalModel)
          scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newVal) {
            if(newVal !== undefined && newVal !== scope.internalModel) {
              scope.internalModel = newVal;
            }
          });
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

The template, `scripts/directives/myCurrencyInput/myCurrencyInput.html` is:

```
<div class="my-currency-input">
  <input type="text" ng-model="internalModel" />
</div>
```

The problem is that right now both the `<div>` (original `<input>` element) and the new `<input>` are being seen as required by the FormController (which handles validation at the form-level). When I run `formCtrl.$removeControl(ngModelCtrl)` inside the link function the ngModelCtrl hasn't yet been attached to the form, but by the time the form gets submitted it has been added.

At this point the only thing I can think of is wrapping `formCtrl.$removeControl(ngModelCtrl)` in a `$timeout`, but that doesn't seem like the correct way of doing this. What's the correct way?

I'm using Angular 1.0.7

Comment: may be a filter could be a better way to go without touching the directive if your goal it's only add a $ sign

Comment: Can you use filters to format values within an input? I thought they were only for displaying bound data (more in 1-way data binding scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

How about making it simply appear as if the '$' sign was in the text box? [See here](http://jsbin.com/lemuruhi/1/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
  .currency-input{
    padding:.3em;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#fff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 3px #ddd;
    border:solid 1px #aaa;
    font-size:14px;
  }
  .currency-input input{
    border:0px;
    outline:0px;
    font-size:14px;
  }
  <style>
</head>
<body>  
  <div class='currency-input'>
    $<input />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is I want the directive to be self-contained in terms of HTML markup (the beautiful thing about directives). Putting the `$` outside the directive almost defeats the purpose of making this directive.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this works by wrapping `formCtrl.$removeControl(ngModelCtrl)` in a `$timeout` with no timeout value. So

```
if($input.attr('required') === 'required') {
  // formCtrl doesn't have ngModelCtrl attached at this point
  formCtrl.$removeControl(ngModelCtrl);
}
```

becomes

```
if($input.attr('required') === 'required') {
  // formCtrl doesn't have ngModelCtrl attached at this point
  $timeout(function() {
    formCtrl.$removeControl(ngModelCtrl);
  });
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what's preventing that from running synchronously, but for now it will do (at work, can't spend much more time on it).